# numpy mean of rows when speed is a concern

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I want to do mean of rows of numpy matrix. So for the input:

```
array([[ 1,  1, -1],
       [ 2,  0,  0],
       [ 3,  1,  1],
       [ 4,  0, -1]])
```

my output will be:

```
  array([[ 0.33333333],
         [ 0.66666667],
         [ 1.66666667],
         [ 1.        ]])
```

I came up with a solution `result = array([[x] for x in np.mean(my_matrix, axis=1)])`, but this function will be called a lots of times on matrices of 40rows x 10-300 columns, so i would like to make it faster, and this implementation seems slow

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
>>> my_matrix.mean(axis=1)[:,np.newaxis]
array([[ 0.33333333],
       [ 0.66666667],
       [ 1.66666667],
       [ 1.        ]])
```

Comment: Note that in newer versions of numpy, you can say `my_matrix.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True)` if you want to keep the reduced dimension as a trivial (i.e. length 1) dimension.  (I don't recall which version added this feature.)

Answer (score 0):

If the matrices are fresh and independent there isn't much you can save because the only way to compute the mean is to actually sum the numbers.

If however the matrices are obtained from partial views of a single fixed dataset (e.g. you're computing a moving average) the you can use a sum table. For example after:

```
st = data.cumsum(0)
```

you can compute the average of the elements between index `x0` and `x1` with

```
avg = (st[x1] - st[x0]) / (x1 - x0)
```

in O(1) (i.e. the computing time doesn't depends on how many elements you are averaging).

You can even use numpy to compute an array with the moving averages directly with:

```
res = (st[n:] - st[:-n]) / n
```

This approach can even be extended to higher dimensions like computing the average of the values in a rectangle in O(1) with

```
st = data.cumsum(0).cumsum(1)
rectsum = (st[y1][x1] + st[y0][x0] - st[y0][x1] - st[y1][x0])
```